# ArcGIS ModelBuilder task

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, clip

I have a .shp file(A) with several polygons in it. I need to clip other .shp file(B) by each one of the polygons from the first one(A) and save the results in seperate file.

How can I do that using  ModelBuilder in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import your shapefiles into a geodatabase, create a toolbox in this geodatabase.

Create a model, drag your feature class(a) into the model, go the Insert tab, choose iterators, and add in Field Value.

Set up this iterator to go over your feature class(a) on a unique field for each polygon. Add in your clip tool, and your feature class(b).

Create a line from the result of the iterator, connect to the clip tool, and determine an output.

This model should iterate over every polygon in feature class(a), clip to feature class(b), create an output, then move on to the next polygon in (a). Good luck!